# a word for "trickster god" or "ambivalent demon"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an appropriate or clever word that could be used to describe a sort-of deity that was not entirely evil or benevolent but would behave in an evil or benevolent way for its own amusement? Perhaps "demon" is still the optimal existing choice.

Comment: 'Trickster' is in fact the usual term of art in anthropological and literary studies of mythology.

Comment: In most modern english-speaking contexts, a "demon" is a decidedly evil creature.

Comment: [***Hermes***](http://www.igreekmythology.com/hermes.html)

Comment: 'Sprite' might be a possibility for a supernatural creature with those characteristics but it would have to be a very minor sort of deity that you were talking about.

Comment: Yes, @Hank, Hermes is one example, but let us not forget Loki, Wenebojo, and many others.

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest ***puckish***, which is synonymous with ***impish*** and ***whimsical***.

It's origin is likely from Shakespeare's character in *A Midsummer Night's Dream*.

> We know Puck as "that merry wanderer of the night," the shape-changing, maiden-frightening, mischief-sowing henchman to the king of the fairies in Shakespeare's *A Midsummer Night's Dream*. The Bard drew on English folklore in casting his character, but the traditional Puck was more malicious than the Shakespearean imp; he was an evil spirit or demon. In medieval England, this nasty hobgoblin was known as the *puke* or *pouke*, names related to the Old Norse *pŪki*, meaning "devil." But it was the Bard's characterization that stuck, and by the time the adjective puckish started appearing regularly in English texts in the late 1800s the association was one of impishness, not evil.
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puckish)</sub>

Comment: _Impish_ sounds more like it.

Comment: Puck is a really great one. If only it didn't also mean a hockey cylinder. Calling someone a puck might confuse a lot of folks.